# Sonata News Bundle composer require error

Tags: symfony, composer-php

My composer json key "require":

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
        "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.0",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^2.4",
        "excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle": "^1.4",
        "rusdteam/php-js": "dev-master",
        "gries/rcon": "^0.0.3",
        "friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle": "^2.0",
        "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "dev-master",
        "idma/robokassa": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/news-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/classification-bundle": "~2.2@dev"
    },
```

In the end I added sonata news bundle, but after I run "composer update" this return error:

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for sonata-project/news-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by sonata-project/news-bundle[dev-master].
    - sonata-project/news-bundle dev-master requires sonata-project/datagrid-bundle ~2.2 -> no matching package found.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle[dev-master].
    - sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle dev-master requires sonata-project/admin-bundle ~2.4@dev -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

What I should add to dependencies for it works?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to switch from `dev-master` to a more specific version on both problematic packages:

```
    "sonata-project/news-bundle": "^2.3",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^2.3",
```

---

Ok, some more tweaks:

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
        "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.0",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^2.4",
        "excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle": "^1.4",
        "rusdteam/php-js": "dev-master",
        "gries/rcon": "^0.0.3",
        "friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle": "^2.0",
        "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "*",
        "idma/robokassa": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/news-bundle": "^2.3",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^2.3",
        "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/classification-bundle": "~2.2@dev"
    }
}
```

This resolves and fetches the packages, when running

`composer install -vvv --profile`

(I've added `--ignore-platform-reqs` to the cmd, because the sockets extension is missing here.)

Comment: Ok, i've tweaked some more version constraints. added sonata-project/datagrind-bundle dev-master, ckeditor-bundle to * and friendsofsymfony/user-bundle to *. Using * wildcard is not nice, but let composer do the lookup and be more specific later. I've tested it - takes ages to resolve, but works.